# How do I print out an ArrayList<Integer> from a HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, hashset

I have a `HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Its printed format is:

```
[ [1, 2], [11, 22], [111, 222] ]
```

Now, if I just want to print out the last `Array<Integer>` which is `[111, 222]`, how do I do that? Is there any similar method to `indexOf()` for a `HashSet`?

Comment: Set is onordered collection.

Answer (score 3):

You can't as there is no order inside a Set, and therefore no index. So your "last" element is not always the same. If you need them to be in order you could use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Or you iterate over all elements of the Set and find the one you want to print like that.

Answer (score 1):

Elements in a HashSet aren't stored in any defined order. So asking fo the "last" element of a HashSet doesn't make sense.

If you need an ordered set, then use a LinkedHashSet.

If you need a sorted set, then use a TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` does not maintain order, so you will not be able to use API such as `indexOf()` with `HashSet`. You need to use `List` in place of Set to get the `indexOf()` last element.

```
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    // Add elements in the list

    list .indexOf(list.size()-1); // This will fetch you the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can iterate to the last element and print it:

```
Iterator i = set.iterator();
List last = null;
while(i.hasNext()) 
   last = i.next();
...
```

Or you can transform the set into a list and get the last element:

```
List list = new ArrayList(set);
List last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
...
```

Comment: Good algorithms give the same output for the same input. Set does not preserve order so you can try your code, but do not recommend it to others.

Comment: the last one will not necessarily be always the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate till the last element and print only the last one.

Best way would be if you use TreeSet instead of HashSet.